# SQL Server SQL "down filling" data that doesn't exist in source table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table that just has dates in it. Then I have a table that has some dimensions and 1 fact column. One of the dimension is also date, but there are less dates than the first table. The first table has every 1st of each month back 20 years and forward 20 years.

I want to join the 2 tables where the final result is that every date in the date table is represented and filled in with the data from the 2nd table. When there is no data between 2 given dates from the fact table I want to fill that in with the last known data.

So the table structure of the date table is just 1 column which is a date and it's filled in with the 1st of each month for 40 years.

The second table is defined as: company (varchar), type (varchar), dt (datetime), value (float)

Let's say I have values in the second table like:

```
'Company A', 'Retail', '5/1/2014', 3.5
'Company A', 'Retail', '7/1/2014', 4
```

Notice how there is no 6/1/2014 record in this table, but this date record exists in the date table. So when I'm finished with the query the result should look like:

```
'Company A', 'Retail', '5/1/2014', 3.5
'Company A', 'Retail', '6/1/2014', 3.5
'Company A', 'Retail', '7/1/2014', 4
```

Notice how the 3.5 and all other fields (except date) carried downward into the missing date record. The order of this becomes very important as you can tell.

I'm not sure if this can be done with a query, but the results need to be passed around to things that required a query/table and not a stored proc, and having some kind of process to update a table like this won't really work well as the entry of this data is done via a website with many users where the results should be instant.

Hope that makes sense, and any help our thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what sql server you useing?

Comment: Do you want summary data? Or is it guaranteed that the data in your fact table will only have 1 record for each date point mentioned in the date table?

Comment: SQL Server 2012.

No summary data. The detail. The final result should have every single date that's in the fact table AND the date table.

Comment: What is the primary key for table 2?

Comment: If I take your meaning correctly, if there's a date in the fact table of 05/02/2013, you want that record as well?

Comment: Correct Jaaz. Love, the PK would be company, retail, & dt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your fact table only has info for the first of each month, then this should work for you. If your fact table has other pieces of information, then you will most likely grab that data. i.e. if you have data for May 30th, that information will be inserted for the June 1st date.

```
SELECT t2.company, t2.type, t1.dt, t2.value
FROM tbldata t1,
      tblfact t2
WHERE t2.dt <= t1.dt
AND   NOT EXISTS (SELECT top 1 1
                  FROM tblfact t22
                  WHERE t22.dt <= t1.dt
                  AND   t22.dt > t2.dt)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d523/6)

Comment: The majority of the dates are firsts of each month, but if tbldata has other dates is there a way to preserve those dates? I suppose do some check for t2.dt is null and if so then use t1.dt else t2.dt?

Comment: (assuming tbldata is your date only table) This code will preserve those dates. This code is saying that we want the fact with the most recent date to match up to the date in tbldata. If tbldata has '3-7' and tblfact has '3-4', these pieces of information will be matched up. If tblfact also has '3-7', that piece of information will be given priority and the information from '3-4' will be ignored. The real issue is if tblfact has more dates than tbldata. if tblfact has '3-7', '3-12', and '4-1' while tbldata has '3-7' and '4-1', the '3-12' record in tblfact will not be matched to anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my not so nice example:

```
DECLARE @Dates TABLE (dates datetime)

INSERT INTO @Dates SELECT '5/1/2014'
INSERT INTO @Dates SELECT '6/1/2014'
INSERT INTO @Dates SELECT '7/1/2014'
INSERT INTO @Dates SELECT '8/1/2014'
INSERT INTO @Dates SELECT '9/1/2014'
INSERT INTO @Dates SELECT '10/1/2014'
INSERT INTO @Dates SELECT '11/1/2014'

DECLARE @data TABLE ( company varchar(100), type varchar(100), dt datetime, value float)

INSERT INTO @data SELECT 'Company A', 'Retail', '5/1/2014', 3.5
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 'Company A', 'Retail', '7/1/2014', 4
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 'Company A', 'Retail', '8/1/2014', 55

;WITH a AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY D.dates) as RowID, dates as dt, company, type, value
    FROM @Dates AS D
    LEFT JOIN @data AS dt
        ON D.dates = dt.dt
), b AS (
    SELECT RowID, company, type, dt, value
    FROM a
    WHERE RowID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        a.RowID, 
        CASE WHEN a.company IS NULL THEN  b.company ELSE a.company ENd,
        CASE WHEN a.company IS NULL THEN  b.type ELSE a.type ENd,
        a.dt,
        CASE WHEN a.company IS NULL THEN  b.value ELSE a.value ENd
    FROM b
    INNER JOIN a
        ON a.RowID = b.RowID+1 

)
SELECT company, type, dt, value
FROM b
```